# Python Text Based game Inventory issues

Tags: python

I'm having issues getting items into the character inventory from the various rooms. It's the final issue I'm having for this particular game.

My "Get" command does not add the room's item to my inventory. The room will list the particular item, so that's not the issue. The issue comes when I use "get [item]". For example (copied directly from my testing):

```
You are in the Northeast Wing
Your Inventory: []
You see the Necklace of Ethereal Inhabitance
Enter your command:Get Necklace of Ethereal Inhabitance
This room doesn't have the Necklace Of Ethereal Inhabitance
```

```
# Function to display character location and inventory
def char_status(rooms, current_room, inventory):
    print("\nYou are in the", current_room)
    print("Your Inventory:", inventory)
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
    print("You see the", rooms[current_room]['item'])


# Movement function
def room_movement(current_room, move, rooms):
    current_room = rooms[current_room][move]
    return current_room


# Add found items to inventory and show inventory list
def acquire(item, inventory, rooms, current_room):
    inventory.append(item)
    del rooms[current_room]['item']
    return inventory


# Game Loop

def main():

    rooms = {
        'Tower Entrance': {'North': 'Throne Room Entrance'},
        'Throne Room Entrance': {'North': 'Throne Room', 'West': 'Southwest Wing', 'East': 'Southeast Wing'},
        'Southwest Wing': {'East': 'Throne Room Entrance', 'item': 'Robe of the Archmagi'},
        'Southeast Wing': {'West': 'Throne Room Entrance', 'item': 'Tome of Clear Thought'},
        'Throne Room': {'West': 'West Wing', 'North': 'North Wing', 'East': 'East Wing', 'South': 'Throne Room Entrance',
                    'item': 'Staff of the Magi'},
        'West Wing': {'North': 'Northwest Wing', 'East': 'Throne Room'},
        'Northwest Wing': {'South': 'West Wing', 'item': 'Bracers of Defense'},
        'East Wing': {'West': 'Throne Room', 'North': 'Northeast Wing'},
        'Northeast Wing': {'South': 'East Wing', 'item': 'Necklace of Ethereal Inhabitance'},
        'North Wing': {'South': 'Throne Room', 'North': "Wizard's Study"},
        "Wizard's Study": {'East': "Wizard's Chamber", 'item': 'Spirit of Friendship'},
        "Wizard's Chamber": {'East': 'Tower Entrance'}
    }

    instructions()  # Display game instructions

    current_room = 'Tower Entrance'  # Starting room

    inventory = []  # List for in-game items

    while True:  # Game Loop

        if current_room == "Wizard's Chamber":
            print('You have arrived at the ', current_room)
            print("Your Inventory:", inventory)

            if len(inventory) != 6:
                print("You arrive at the wizard's chamber, desperate to avenge your fallen companion.")
                print("In your haste for revenge, you failed to fully arm yourself.")
                print("Seeing the vulnerability, the evil wizard launches the same attack on you that was used in the death of your friend.")
                print("This time, there is no one to save you. The wizard's curse hits you with full force.")
                print("You have been killed and with no defenses left, the kingdom falls into darkness.")
                break

            else:
                print("You finally corner the evil wizard in his chamber. Suddenly, he unleashes an ancient curse")
                print("with the intent of completely and utterly destroying your physical and ethereal forms.\n")
                print("The spirit of your friend leaves the safety of the necklace, and shields you from the full force curse attack by the wizard!")
                print("The attack leaves his ethereal form extremely weak and close to vanishing forever. He retreats back into the necklace.\n")
                print("With the evil wizard recovering from his attack, you realize this is your one and only chance to counterattack.")
                print("Using all of the knowledge you learned from your adventure and your mentor")
                print("and the combined power of the reclaimed weapons and armor,")
                print("you unleash a magical attack from your staff toward the wizard.")
                print("The wizard becomes engulfed in a sphere of light. As the light fades,")
                print("blue and purple flames surround the wizard rendering him immobile.\n")
                print("The spirit of your friend appears again, still very weak from his second sacrifice.")
                print("Grasping his sword, he recites an enchantment learned from his warrior teachings.")
                print("The sword begins to shimmer with a golden-white light.")
                print("With all of the remaining strength your friend has left, he swings his sword.")
                print("The sword slices the wizard in half from his head to his feet, disintegrating him from existence.")
                print("Your friend looks back at you with a weak smile and slowly vanishes, to be at peace forever with his ancestors.\n")
                print("You see a glowing light in the eastern side of the room. You walk toward it and enter it's glow.")
                print("The light teleports you back to where you began and your journey, at last, comes to an end!")
                break

        else:
            char_status(rooms, current_room, inventory)

        move = input("Enter your command:").title().split(' ', 1)

        valid_dir = list(rooms[current_room].keys())
        if 'item' in valid_dir:
            valid_dir.remove('item')

        if move[0] == "Exit":
            print("You are leaving the game. Thanks for playing!")
            break

        elif (move[0] == "Go") and (move[1] in valid_dir):
            next_room = room_movement(current_room, move[1], rooms)
            current_room = next_room
            print(" ")

        elif (move[0] == "Go") and (move[1] not in valid_dir):
            print("You cannot go that way!\n")

        # Get item function
        elif (move[0] == 'Get') and (move[1] == rooms[current_room]['item']):
            inventory = acquire(rooms[current_room]['item'], inventory, rooms, current_room)
            print(" ")

        elif (move[0] == 'Get') and (move[1] != rooms[current_room]['item']):
            print("This room doesn't have the", move[1])
            print(" ")

        else:
            print("Invalid command. Please try again.\n")

    print("\nThank you for playing! I hope you enjoyed it!")`
```

Comment: Try not returning the inventory, the append should have been enough. FYI, This design pattern is unusual and likely to become unwieldy. Usually one would have a class and have inventory be an attribute of that class and have room_movement and acquire functions be methods of that class.

Comment: I will definitely remember this suggestion for next time. I'm pretty new when it comes to coding, so I don't have the polish of a seasoned coder yet. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

your main issue is with that line

```py
move = input("Enter your command:").title().split(' ', 1)
```

because you use `title()` so it converted your input "Necklace of Ethereal Inhabitance"  to "Necklace Of Ethereal Inhabitance" converting "of" to "Of" so they didn't equal each other any more

you could remove `.title` or inside any comparison use `.lower()` to make sure you don't have any issues with capital letters

Comment: I will give removing title() a go first to see what happens and go from there. I very much appreciate the suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much for the assistance!!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling `title()` on the user's input, which will turn "Necklace of Ethereal Inhabitance" into "Necklace **O**f Ethereal Inhabitance". Now the comparison of this string with the original "Necklace of Ethereal Inhabitance" using `==` returns False.

So you need to fix your comparsion to:

```
        elif move[0] == 'Get' and move[1] == rooms[current_room]['item'].title():
```

(There is no need for the parenthesis, so I removed them.)

Comment: Another person suggested this as well, so I'm going to try removing title() and see what happens. Seems to get the general consensus. Thank you for your suggestion as well!

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much for the assistance!!!